# Milnor, Lectures on the h-cobordism theorem, proof of Theorem 3.4

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

I have a question while reading the proof of Theorem 3.4 in Milnor's book *Lectures on the h-cobordism theorem*. ([https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/surgery/hcobord.pdf](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/surgery/hcobord.pdf))

**Theorem 3.4.** If the Morse number $\mu$ of the triad $(W;V_0,V_1)$ is zero, then $(W;V_0,V_1)$ is a product cobordism.

Proof) $(\cdots)$ We obtain an integral which satisfies $f(\psi(s))=s$. Each integral curve can be extended uniquely over a maximal interval, which, since $W$ is compact, must be $[0,1]$. $(\cdots)$

My question is: How did the compactness of $W$ used to show that the maximal domain of an integral curve must be $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f$ is assumed to have value $0$ on $V_0$ and $1$ on $V_1$. An integral curve of an ODE/vector field on a compact manifold with boundary can be extended until it hits the boundary. Since $f(\psi(s))=s$ this will happen precisely at $s=0$ and at $s=1$.